# What is the best way to approach presenting different content based on whether a user is logged in or not using Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

This question is not specific to code, but I am wondering if I am approaching the design incorrectly. Basically when a user logs in, they are directed to mysite.com/dashboard/theirusername.
But I also want the ability to have a guest go to that same link and interact with the users dashboard. 
So when someone without an account, who just has an email link to the dashboard goes to it Id like to show them different content and interact with them. 
So my question is this. I started with the logic of if a user is not logged in then show them  different items based on an *ngIf. I started working out the logic on that and then thought maybe there is some sort of routing based solution to this that I am unaware of?
Is it possible to use the same url and show different components based on login status? Or is the *ngIf based on login approach valid?

Thank you for your time,
Mike

Answer (score 1):

The best way to attack this is creating guards, here you can check the documentation about it

https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate

and here is a great medium article about how to manage with http interceptors

[medium](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-route-guards-bf7a4ca13ae3)